# HighCharts - How to combine JS and SQL for two charts?

Tags: mysql, highcharts, function-call

I have two pie charts. First is working fine, I load the data from database in it. I had set a click event on it, which calls function, which contains code for the second chart. In the function I pass the parameter with information on which slice of pie has been clicked. It works. Now: I need to load the data from database in the second chart, just like in the first. Catch is, that I need to pass value in the parameter to the SQL request and then results load in the second chart. But passing JS variables in the PHP is way much beyond my skills. Do the HighCharts has this solved somehow? Is there any "not too much crazy" way to do this? Here´s the jFiddle: `www.jsfiddle.net/r36qe/2/`

Answer (score 2):

You can simply use $.get() or $.getJSON() method and in URL add parameter, for example:

```
$.getJSON('http://www.yourdomain.com/getpie.php?index=' + window.index, function(data) {        
    //create new chart with data from response
});
```

Then in your getpie.php you have access to this variable via:

```
$clickedindex = $_GET['index'];
```

The same way works it for Highcharts example [lazy-loading](http://www.highcharts.com/stock/demo/lazy-loading) and PHP file you can find [here](https://github.com/highslide-software/highcharts.com/blob/master/samples/data/from-sql.php).

Comment: Thanks for answer! But will this work if I have the charts on the same page in jQuery tab? I cannot refresh or something...

Comment: $.getJSON() is method to get some live data from server without refreshing page. Here you can read more about [AJAX](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/) and [getJSON](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.getJSON/)

Comment: Sorry Im maybe little slow or Im missing something :) I put getJSON in my function like this: http://jsfiddle.net/r36qe/3/ now it just should throw some alert...but its doing nothing...even if I put code for the chart instead of that alert according to your answer. What am I doing wrong? The fiddle isnt working by the way, I think because of the URL...but at least you can see how I wrote it.

Comment: PHP code should be inside your PHP file (like in example in my first post). Also, it's not possible to get JSON due to [same origin policy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same_origin_policy). In our example we are using JSONP, which is not necessary in your case.

Comment: I got every piece of code in the same file, I don´t have any other...Everything is in this one, kalk_graphs.php

Comment: I used $.get(); instead, now it shows that alert but instead of value of index, it just says "undefined"...Im not sure if I understand your advices, sorry for that... I have much to learn yet :)

Comment: I gave it some thought and I think I finally understand how you meant it...To make another file with chart and to load that file with parameter in some div on my "main" page...